# I am unable to login into azure using my system powershell

Tags: azure, authentication

A web browser has been opened at `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`. Please continue the login in the web browser.

If no web browser is available or if the web browser fails to open, use device code flow with `az login --use-device-code`.

The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
0. The ID token is not yet valid. Current epoch = 1647701015.  The id_token was:

```
{
  "aud": "04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a/v2.0",
  "iat": 1647758308,
  "nbf": 1647758308,
  "exp": 1647762208,
  "aio": "AWQAm/8TAAAAbgJkMiJR8PdsfO1GPPEosOG/5hV/j3oxBHQp6raI1BqcDpHGvnmQA21+14pe4oecjksG/F7k2LPRBBspcv47KMEyRzTZdMtqc5nchbPpz6ao7BP09kwzzwR/6Osduu2b",       
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad/",
  "nonce": "247c39ea219116253e096752684d7d9047a11fc9b5be9e13a4e959e79cd43339",
  "preferred_username": "olukayodefadairo@gmail.com",
  "rh": "0.AXkAMe_N-B6jSkuT5F9XHpElWpV3sATbjRpGu-4C-eG_e0YBACA.",
  "sub": "6yU4HdKdeIr7BQdwa8LNSqBro_DsGFOglTgNywy5LL0",
  "tid": "f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a",
  "uti": "oKnBp4WwOkqMzbJaPgIbAA",
  "ver": "2.0"
}
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/cli.py`", line 231, in invoke

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py`", line 658, in execute

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py`", line 721, in _run_jobs_serially

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py`", line 692, in _run_job

File "D`:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py`", line 328, in **call**

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py`", line 121, in handler

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/profile/custom.py`", line 139, in login

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/_profile.py`", line 155, in login

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/auth/identity.py`", line 171, in login_with_auth_code

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/application.py`", line 1546, in acquire_token_interactive

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/oauth2cli/oidc.py`", line 280, in obtain_token_by_browser

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/oauth2cli/oauth2.py`", line 640, in obtain_token_by_browser

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/oauth2cli/oauth2.py`", line 678, in _obtain_token_by_browser

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/application.py`", line 135, in obtain_token_by_auth_code_flow

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/oauth2cli/oidc.py`", line 204, in obtain_token_by_auth_code_flow

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/oauth2cli/oauth2.py`", line 548, in obtain_token_by_auth_code_flow

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/oauth2cli/oauth2.py`", line 732, in _obtain_token_by_authorization_code

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/oauth2cli/oidc.py`", line 115, in _obtain_token

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/oauth2cli/oauth2.py`", line 789, in _obtain_token

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/application.py`", line 581, in

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/token_cache.py`", line 307, in add

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/token_cache.py`", line 113, in add

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/token_cache.py`", line 152, in __add

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/oauth2cli/oidc.py`", line 76, in decode_id_token

RuntimeError: 0. The ID token is not yet valid. Current epoch = 1647701015.  The id_token was:

```
{
  "aud": "04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a/v2.0",
  "iat": 1647758308,
  "nbf": 1647758308,
  "aio": "AWQAm/8TAAAAbgJkMiJR8PdsfO1GPPEosOG/5hV/j3oxBHQp6raI1BqcDpHGvnmQA21+14pe4oecjksG/F7k2LPRBBspcv47KMEyRzTZdMtqc5nchbPpz6ao7BP09kwzzwR/6Osduu2b",       
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad/",
  "nonce": "247c39ea219116253e096752684d7d9047a11fc9b5be9e13a4e959e79cd43339",
  "preferred_username": "olukayodefadairo@gmail.com",
  "rh": "0.AXkAMe_N-B6jSkuT5F9XHpElWpV3sATbjRpGu-4C-eG_e0YBACA.",
  "sub": "6yU4HdKdeIr7BQdwa8LNSqBro_DsGFOglTgNywy5LL0",
  "tid": "f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a",
  "uti": "oKnBp4WwOkqMzbJaPgIbAA",
  "ver": "2.0"
}
```

To open an issue, please run: '`az feedback`'

PS C:\terra1\IaC> `az login`
A web browser has been opened at https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize.

Please continue the login in the web browser.

If no web browser is available or if the web browser fails to open, use device code flow with az login --use-device-code.
The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
0. The ID token is not yet valid. Current epoch = 1647701078.  The id_token was:

```
{
  "aud": "04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a/v2.0",
  "iat": 1647758371,
  "nbf": 1647758371,
  "exp": 1647762271,
  "aio": "AWQAm/8TAAAA+GPjbTIe9Rn40PC0BGOSJgDlfVyV8kjpkz3SKN8zZBt5sLxdGoxwJeWWXpYQuTt0AXJuCaduCdL9Fx0VU6E/CPDe+z4nYQeMjtZzYhhumRsDAaBrwzDrPJgrUMbOvp8I",       
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad/",
  "nonce": "691fe40cfbb6fe73b7bc5e35d7d9d5e770d6ad3ab38decf613bc23cc24700cc6",
  "preferred_username": "olukayodefadairo@gmail.com",
  "rh": "0.AXkAMe_N-B6jSkuT5F9XHpElWpV3sATbjRpGu-4C-eG_e0YBACA.",
  "sub": "6yU4HdKdeIr7BQdwa8LNSqBro_DsGFOglTgNywy5LL0",
  "tid": "f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a",
  "uti": "wv2wxQybl0SLg_JbyIwZAA",
  "ver": "2.0"
}
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/cli.py`", line 231, in invoke

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py`", line 658, in execute

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py`", line 721, in _run_jobs_serially

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py`", line 692, in _run_job

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py`", line 328, in **call**

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py`", line 121, in handler

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/profile/custom.py`", line 139, in login

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/_profile.py`", line 155, in login

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/auth/identity.py`", line 171, in login_with_auth_code

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/application.py`", line 1546, in acquire_token_interactive

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/oauth2cli/oidc.py`", line 280, in obtain_token_by_browser

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/oauth2cli/oauth2.py`", line 640, in obtain_token_by_browser

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/oauth2cli/oauth2.py`", line 678, in _obtain_token_by_browser

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/application.py`", line 135, in obtain_token_by_auth_code_flow

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/oauth2cli/oidc.py`", line 204, in obtain_token_by_auth_code_flow

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/oauth2cli/oauth2.py`", line 548, in obtain_token_by_auth_code_flow

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/oauth2cli/oauth2.py`", line 732, in _obtain_token_by_authorization_code

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/oauth2cli/oidc.py`", line 115, in _obtain_token

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/oauth2cli/oauth2.py`", line 789, in _obtain_token

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/application.py`", line 581, in

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/token_cache.py`", line 307, in add

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/token_cache.py`", line 113, in add

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/token_cache.py`", line 152, in __add

File "`D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/oauth2cli/oidc.py`", line 76, in decode_id_token

RuntimeError: 0. The ID token is not yet valid. Current epoch = 1647701078.  The id_token was:

```
{
  "aud": "04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a/v2.0",
  "iat": 1647758371,
  "nbf": 1647758371,
  "aio": "AWQAm/8TAAAA+GPjbTIe9Rn40PC0BGOSJgDlfVyV8kjpkz3SKN8zZBt5sLxdGoxwJeWWXpYQuTt0AXJuCaduCdL9Fx0VU6E/CPDe+z4nYQeMjtZzYhhumRsDAaBrwzDrPJgrUMbOvp8I",       
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad/",
  "nonce": "691fe40cfbb6fe73b7bc5e35d7d9d5e770d6ad3ab38decf613bc23cc24700cc6",
  "preferred_username": "olukayodefadairo@gmail.com",
  "rh": "0.AXkAMe_N-B6jSkuT5F9XHpElWpV3sATbjRpGu-4C-eG_e0YBACA.",
  "sub": "6yU4HdKdeIr7BQdwa8LNSqBro_DsGFOglTgNywy5LL0",
  "tid": "f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a",
  "uti": "wv2wxQybl0SLg_JbyIwZAA",
  "ver": "2.0"
}
```

To open an issue, please run: '`az feedback`'

Comment: Hi there, could you please format your question ? It is not really readable at the moment :-9

Answer (score 1):

To **login** to the **Azure Account** from your **System PowerShell**, few of the workarounds with various commands like ***browser authentication***, ***device code login*** (If no browser available) using both **PowerShell** and **CLI Commands** were:

**Note**: In the browser, you can use the ***current user*** option if you're already logged in before and saved the credentials or you can also ***enter the password*** option if credentials are not saved, or you can also use ***login with the different account*** option to sign-in into another Azure Account.

---

**AZ CLI Command with Device Login**: **`az login --use-device-code`** and below is how it works:

[image: azlogindevicecodeuse]

**PowerShell Command with Device Login**: **`Connect-AzAccount -DeviceCode`** and below is how it works:

[image: powershellusedevicelogin]

**PowerShell Command**: **`Connect-AZAccount`** and below is how it works:

It will open the azure portal credential popup dialog box in portal.

[image]

**AZ CLI Command**: **`az login`** and below is how it works:

It will open the azure portal credential popup dialog box in portal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found that the some of the files  in

> C:\Users<user_name>.azure

folder has been corrupted.

In order to fix the issue please try deleting the *.azure* folder. Please make sure to take a backup of the folder before deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows, follow these steps:

1. Go to windows search and type "Change the date and the time" and open it.
2. Click on "Sync now" button like the photo below:

[image]

3. try again to login via cmd  `>az login`

Answer (score 0):

In a linux machine you can use the following commands

First identify the timezone

```
cat /etc/timezone
```

Find the current 24 hour format time for that timezone . Lets say "20:34:47"

Update the time

```
sudo timedatectl set-time '20:34:47'
```